# Biztalk, need to consume a web service

Tags: biztalk

What I need to do to send a request and to receive answer from the Web Service that I want to consume.

What i have done:

1. I have done the "add web Reference"
2. I added a `Send Shape` and a `Receive Shape` and a I configured a port that sent and received with web Type, the port binding `Specify later` and I connect with the Request and response to the Send and Receive shape.

I believe I am missing something ?

Comment: In addition to Yossi's blog link, there's another [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995454/using-biztalk-web-service-to-re-publish-an-internal-web-service/18037175#18037175) about integrating with WCF services - obviously you don't need to do the need the republishing bit.

Answer (score 1):

From your description I am guessing you might be missing -

1. A definition of the request and
   response messages; you need to
   ensure you have a request and
   response message defined, with their
   types being the generated web types.
2. Select the correct message for both
   the send and receive shape. send
   shape uses the request message,
   receive shape uses the response
   message.
3. Construct the request message using a construct and a transform or assignment shape before the send shape. the easiest way to get started is to use a map in a transform shape to create the request from whatever message triggered your process, but the exact implementation detail will, of course, depend on your scenario

This should be enough to call the service I would have thought
There are many blog posts on the subject, [here's](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article296.aspx) one I found with a quick search that shows all the pieces needed

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working my way through a project using Biztalk to consume a web service.  I think you may have a error when compiling similar to :

"Use of unreconstructed message"

If this is the problem, add a construct message shape to the orchestration before the send to the web service port.

I'm stuck with creating the message syntax but this should get you moving.